# Python - invalid literal error with fusiontables table id

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-fusion-tables

I have got [this example](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-python/source/browse/trunk/src/samples/clientlogin_example.py) for inserting data into funsiontables...

The code basically creates a new table and store its id into a variable to support the insert, update or delete functions. The code is from 2010/2011 and I think google has change table_id format since then because I am getting the error below in the following line:

```
return 'INSERT INTO %d (%s) VALUES (%s)' % \
  (int(table_id), ','.join(["'%s'" % col for col in cols]), stringValues)
```

Error:

```
 (int(table_id), ','.join(["'%s'" % col for col in cols]), stringValues)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1PHHo1h0tA0VxI09mAH0AH_IDNUpN5Hm-aTaAqO0'
```

I could simply change it to a simple SQL statement, but I am sure I will need to handle table_id or row_id in the next steps of the project. So, I would like to keep the way it has been done and if possible fix it. However, I could not understand the problem in the conversion to int over the table_id "1PHHo1h0tA0VxI09mAH0AH_IDNUpN5Hm-aTaAqO0"...

The function int() supports any integer or string...

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `table_id` does not appear to be a numeric integer.

You could try to modify the code as follows:

```
return 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)' % \
 (table_id, ','.join(["'%s'" % col for col in cols]), stringValues)
```

In other words, using `table_id` as a simple string.